# iOS 8 detecting device orientation at application launch

Tags: ios, iphone, orientation, ios8

The method [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] is not returning the correct value at application launch. Is this an API beta bug or is there a new method to detect orientation in iOS 8?

Here's the exact code 'm using at application launch.

```
UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait){
}
else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
    [self orientationLandscapeLeftAdjust];
}
else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight){
    [self orientationLandscapeRightAdjust];
}
else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
    [self orientationPortraitUpSideDownAdjust];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is a bug related to the "No sim card" alert messaged popping up every time  an application is launched in iOS 8 beta 5. This forces the application to launch in it's default orientation. I read that this bug has been addressed in iOS 8 beta 6 which was distributed to carriers and other test partners.